# How to fit a set of 3D data points using a third or higher degree of polynomial surface regression?

Tags: python, algorithm, regression, surface, non-linear-regression

I have input data points (x,y,z), all positive, and need to fit them to a surface. More specifically, I have to create a grid from the x and y data points and evaluate the data points on this grid to obtain a surface of z-values to plot.

How can I do a 3rd or higher polynomial regression to fit a surface to my data points?

The degree of the polynomial regression should preferably be an input value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-linear 3D surface fitter with 3D scatter plot, 3D surface plot, and contour plot. This should be all of the graphs.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, alpha, beta):
    t = data[0]
    p_p = data[1]
    return a * (t**alpha) * (p_p**beta)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could show us your attempt. I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but here are two initial pointers:

Your 2D polynomial (of arbitrary degree) can be defined using [`polyval2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d.html) from the numpy library.

You can then fit this function (e.g., using the least-squares method) with the scipy library: [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).